# Is there anyway to scrape flash in this format?

Tags: flash, screen-scraping

is it possible to scrape this applet http://www.text118118.com/livefeed.aspx

Its not possible to do it traditionally as the text is within the applet however is it possible to do it with a macro.

The feeds loops after 8 questions and the text stays highlighted?

Comment: we're all dreadful of unknown links. Please try to post the code or what here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a look, the app seems to pull its feed data from:
http://www.text118118.com/data/livefeed_test.aspx

(using a proxy server I was able to see this, there are other ways, such as installing the LiveHTTPHeaders in Firefox)

Comment: They also have http://www.text118118.com/data/livefeed.aspx not sure what the difference is yet!